# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails CONSTRAINT `PageChild_Page_Id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`PageId`) REFERENCES `Page` (`Id`)

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I'm using Sails and Waterline for my model associations and I'm not sure what to do in order to fix this error I'm receiving when trying to update a PageChild object.

```
module.exports = {
    tableName: 'Page',
    adapter: 'mysql',
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,

    attributes: {

        Id: {type: 'integer', autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true},

        pageChildren: {
            collection: 'PageChild',
            via: 'Page'
        }
    },
};

module.exports = {
    tableName: 'PageChild',
    adapter: 'mysql',

    attributes: {

        Id: {type: 'integer', autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true},

        Page: {
            model: 'Page',
            columnName: 'PageId'
        }
    }
};
```

The model associations work perfectly fine for populating pageChildren from the Page object or for returning the Page object from any of the pageChildren. However, I encounter this foreign key issue when attempting to create or update a PageChild object.

In the mysql db, the Page table has an "Id" attribute while the PageChild table has "Id" and "PageId" attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this means is that the `ParentId` that you add or update on the child row needs to exist on the `Parent` table.

So, this constraint means that you can't insert a row into `PageChild` with `PageId = 50` if you don't have a row in `Page` that has an `id` with a value of 50.

For example, if you want to create a new page, you have to first create an entry in the `Page` table, then retrieve it's `id` value and only then can you start doing your inserts into the `PageChild` table using the id of the `Page` you made earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explanatory:

```
foreign key constraint fails CONSTRAINT `PageChild_Page_Id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`PageId`) REFERENCES `Page` (`Id`)
```

The rule is, you can only add or update a value in child table which are already present in parent table. So at the time of insertion make sure the value you are trying to insert in child table, already exist in parent table.